# "Browse the web with Microsoft Edge" popup when logging in the first time

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

When I have created a user account using "Computer management" and that user logs in for the first time (deselecting all optional features) a popup for Microsoft edge comes up.

[image: Ad for microsoft edge]

Can I get rid of that behavior? I want an ad free experience for new users.

## Notifications & actions settings

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a screenshot of `Notifications & actions` within Settings.  It also will help if you indicate which version of Windows 10 you are running.

Comment: I have non of those checkboxes checked. I am running Windows 10 PRO version 20H2, build 19042.685.

Comment: I really need that screenshot.  If your using 20H2 then Microsoft Edge is already installed.  I presume what you provide is a notification instead of something that appeared in the Start Menu?

Comment: Hard to say what it is actually.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: It's extremely easy to say what it is, where is it appearing on your screen, near the action  center or the start menu?

Comment: It appears in the lower right corner. I can read "no new notifcations" when hovering the speech bubble in the tray.

Comment: When checking the process list, it seems like its Microsoft Edge actually that in some way has got permission to run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118374/discussion-between-ramhound-and-anders-linden).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get rid of that behavior? I want an ad free experience for new users.

This was suppose to be handled by option `Get tips, tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows` within Settings -> Notifications  but you confirmed within our [conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118374/discussion-between-ramhound-and-anders-linden) that `SoftLandingEnabled` was set to `1` not `0`.

In order to disable the notification presented in your question you must set `SoftLandingEnabled` within `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager` to `0`.

> [image]

`Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Cloud Content` is the group policy that would configure this behavior but is only applicable to Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education.  So the best way to resolve this problem is with a simple PowerShell script offline.

It appears that if you set `DisableHelpSticker`  within `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent` to `1` you will disable these tips for all users.

Sources:

- [Turn On or Off App Suggestions in Start in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24117-turn-off-app-suggestions-start-windows-10-a-3.html)
- [How to Turn On or Off Tips, Tricks, and Suggestions Notifications about Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/30869-turn-off-tip-trick-suggestion-notifications-windows-10-a.html#option2)
- [Disable tips about Windows 10](https://winaero.com/disable-tips-about-windows-10/)